# 404 page displayed when using customize feature (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, customization

When I choose the customize feature on my wordpress website I am shown a 404 page. For every link I try to navigate to throughout the website I am still only given the 404. I can go to the dashboard and edit pages there fine but not with the customize feature. Not sure what is causing this, any help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: Please add at least some info about your customization feature

Comment: I am using the theme "Themify Agency" and when viewing the actual page in the browser if you select the "customize" option in the wordpress navbar it allows you to customize the page while viewing it in real time. Adding text, boxes or images, its useful to see updates and play with development.

Comment: Reset the permalinks once

Comment: still getting the 404